# How to fill Data Grid View dynamically (run time) in C# Win-Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, dynamic, datagridview

I have one application which can communicate with a connected hardware. When I turn on the hardware, the hardware will continuously send some data to the application. I am able to read the data from hardware in my application.

Now I want to record this data to a Grid View continuously(whenever the application receive data, a new row needs to be added to the Grid View and fill the data in that row).

(Or please show me how to add new row in a grid view in each 1 second and add some data in to it at run time)

Please help. I am new to c#.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the demo for you. I suppose your data is of type `Info` as defined below, you can change the `Properties` accordingly depending on your data structure (which is received from the hardware):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
   public Form1(){
      InitializeComponent();
      dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;//if you don't want this, just remove it.
      dataGridView1.DataSource = data;
      Timer t = new Timer(){Interval = 1000};
      t.Tick += UpdateGrid;
      t.Start();
   }     
   private void UpdateGrid(object sender, EventArgs e){
      char c1 = (char)rand.Next(65,97);
      char c2 = (char)rand.Next(65,97);
      data.Add(new Info() {Field1 = c1.ToString(), Field2 = c2.ToString()});
      dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = data.Count - 1;//This will keep the last added row visible with vertical scrollbar being at bottom.
   }
   BindingList<Info> data = new BindingList<Info>();
   Random rand = new Random();
   //the structure of your data including only 2 fields to test
   public class Info
   {
        public string Field1 { get; set; }
        public string Field2 { get; set; }
   }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you get the data some where in the object or variable, then this will work for you.

```
// suppose you get the data in the object test which has two fields field1 and field2, then you can add them in the grid using below code:

grdView.Rows.Add(test.field1, test.field2);
```

I hope it will help you.. :)